# Sticky footer situation with content div being horizontally centered and 100% in height

Tags: css, html, height, centering, sticky-footer

I am trying to incorporate sticky footer and or header onto a site where the content on each page fluctuates, some pages have only a paragraph or less of text and some have multiple paragraphs.

I'd like the white backgrounded div to fill up 100% of the page between the header and footer so that no matter how much content is in the page or how large the viewer's resolution is the white div will be 100% vertically (minus the header and footer.)

I have been tinkering with this area of code:

```
#middle-cell {
  vertical-align:top;
  height: 100%
}
```

Here is [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/secondcodehiker/zb7zL/) of what I have so far.

But so far I haven't been able to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/helion3/details/FAElH)

CSS has no direct way to automatically fill the *remaining* height of a container (not counting some not-fully-supported flexbox features).

If you have a fixed-height header, a percentage-based height for the content will never work properly because the fixed-height is really a different percentage of the viewport at every size.

The solution is to add a new `position: absolute` div that *wraps* the content of the page, it acts like a new "viewport" when you attach all four sides where you need.

If your header is `height: 60px` then you can attach the edges of your new wrapper like this:

- `top: 60px` - Attaches the top edge below your header
- `bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0` - Attaches the left/right/bottom edges
  of the div to the edge of the body.

What's nice is that the browser *does* know how to calculate the height of this div, so if you have `div.content` inside of it set to `height: 100%` the 100% refers to the height of the remaining screen space after the header.

If the `div.content` has too much text/media, and is longer than the wrapper, simply use `overflow-y: scroll` on the wrapper div and it will let you scroll the content.

Comment: Can you explain this further for me?  I don't quite understand yet.  Example?  At some point I read that two nested divs can't both be set to percentages... one must be fixed size and one can then be a percentage?  Is that what you mean by absolute?  I know there is an absolute attribute... I guess I better read up on that too since I am not too familiar with it.

Comment: I've updated my answer to explain this in better detail

Comment: Thanks for your help, description and clarification.

Comment: I have been working on this in different forms from different walk throughs on the internet, getting no where near to where I want to go with the code for about the past 8+ hours so I am fried and have probably hit my point of just not being able to be productive while I am looking at this code today.  Here is another example I was working on, with some of your suggestions implemented poorly as it is broken in many ways.  :/  [another js fiddle that is similar - from css stickyfooter.com](http://jsfiddle.net/secondcodehiker/XYAw8/)

Comment: Maybe this will help give you an idea, I included some helpful comments in the css: http://jsfiddle.net/XYAw8/1/

Comment: [updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/secondcodehiker/DWMAq/) - still trying to figure out how to center content div so that the orange background is evenly distributed to both sides of the content.

Comment: If you're trying to center a div, use `margin: 0 auto;`. I also moved the css into the css pane in jsfiddle, for readability: http://jsfiddle.net/DWMAq/1/

Comment: I am curious as to why the wrap div is identified / classified with ID but the content is done as a sub class to wrap?  Is this the proper way to ask this question?  Thank you so much by the way.  I had to leave for class last night and just before I left I saw that you had posted the last fix I couldn't figure out.  I left for class in a much better mood than I was expecting to to say the least.

Comment: There's no real "right-way" it just depends on your design. If you only have one of each, `id`s are fine.

Comment: Gotcha.  Before seeing your code yesterday I hadn't seen code before that was just (nav) and (footer) and then listed in the css without a . or a #... are those reserved words, nav and footer or can any word be used like this?

Comment: `nav` and `footer` are HTML5 elements and are valid in all modern browsers (older version of IE need a special script to make them work). There's several more, you can learn about them with a google search.